# How can I hide extra sized background View in a View?

Tags: swiftui

I have a simple Rectangle which I put a VStack of Numbers in background of that, you can see it in code and pic! the problem is the VStack is taller than Rectangle there for it goes outside of Rectangle, I want the extra part be hidden, How could I solve it?

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    
    let arrayOfHours: [Int] = Array(0...23)
    
    var body: some View {

            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.black.opacity(0.25))
                .frame(height: 200, alignment: .center)
                .padding()
                .background(
                
                    VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 4) {
                        
                        ForEach (arrayOfHours.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                            
                            Text(arrayOfHours[index].description)
                                .font(Font.body.bold())
                            
                        }
                    }
                    .background(Color.yellow)

                )

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your description correctly you need `clipped`, like

[image: demo]

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    
    let arrayOfHours: [Int] = Array(0...23)
    
    var body: some View {

            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.black.opacity(0.25))
                .frame(height: 200, alignment: .center)
                .background(
                
                    VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 4) {
                        
                        ForEach (arrayOfHours.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                            
                            Text(arrayOfHours[index].description)
                                .font(Font.body.bold())
                            
                        }
                    }
                    .background(Color.yellow)

                )
                .clipped()        // << here !!
                .padding()        // should be moved here !!
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Asperi: I am creating and using that Rectangle just because of clipped modification! It is kind of Not good, because my most important codes happening in VStack, which is in background of that Rectangle! can you show my more convenient way than I am using? because the color of that Rectangle is going to be clear.